# Error stating that too much to unpack

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file which contains test data in the form student_id, last_name, test_grades_1, test_grades_2, test_grades_3, test_grades_4 into a dictionary with key as student_id and rest attributes as the values.

CODE:

```
def create_grades_dict(file_name):
    my_dict={}
    file_pointer=open(file_name, "r")
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    for line in data:
        stud_id, last_name, test_1, test_2, test_3, test_4 = line.strip().split(',')
        avg = (test_1 + test_2 + test_3 + test_4)/4.0
        my_dict[stud_id]=[last_name, test_1, test_2, test_3, test_4, avg]
    return my_dict
```

ERROR:

```
Error in evaluating function:
ValueError at line 6
too many values to unpack
```

An example of the input file is shown below. Sample Input Output Assuming that the input file "student_grades.txt" contains the following text:

1000123456, Rubble, Test_3,  80, Test_4 , 80

1000123459, Chipmunk, Test_4, 96, Test_1, 86 , Quiz_1 , 88

Comment: Please post the data inside the file that you're using.

Comment: The line that calculates `avg` is also going to raise a `TypeError`, because `test_1`, `test_2`, etc are strings, not numbers. So you will need to do `float(test_1) + float(test_2), ...`

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 I have added the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error "too many values to unpack" if you do e.g. `a, b = (3, 4, 5)`

Obviously, you have more than six values in the list resulting from `line.strip().split(',')`. I would add a `print` this list to see what's the matter.

```
[...]
for line in data:
    print line.strip().split(',')
```

edit, a guess: the values of the grades might be non-integer and written with a comma. In than case, you should do the `split(', ')` (with the space), if the values are entered with a space... if not, you'll have to search for commas surrounded by digits with a regular expression.

Edit after your edit:
well, the input is completely different from what you described :)

It looks like something like this would do it:

```
for line in data:
    datalist = line.strip().split(',')
    if len(datalist) < 2: 
        continue
    stud_id, last_name = datalist[:2]
    namelist, gradelist = [], []
    for name in datalist[2::2]:
        namelist.append(name.strip())
    for grade in datalist[3::2]:
        gradelist.append(int(grade.strip()))
    namelist.append('avg')
    avg = sum(gradelist)/float(len(gradelist))
    gradelist.append(avg)

    newdict = dict(zip(namelist, gradelist))
    my_dict[stud_id]=[last_name, newdict]
```

now you have a dict with a dict for each id. The inner dict has the labels for the testnames as keys and the grade for each.
To handle it you will have to take into account, that the available tests are different for each student...

Comment: I think you should skip lines where `len(datalist) < 2`, so as to avoid errors. You could also add in something like `sum(gradelist) / float(len(gradelist))` to calculate the average grade of the tests each student has taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as follows:

```
def create_grades_dict(file_name):
    my_dictionary = {}
    file_pointer = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    for line in data:
        student_row = map(str.strip, line.strip().split(','))
        student_id = student_row.pop(0)
        student_lastname = student_row.pop(0)
        student_data = [student_lastname]
        for valid_test in ['Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_3', 'Test_4']:
            if valid_test in student_row:
                student_data.append(int(student_row[student_row.index(valid_test) + 1]))
            else:
                student_data.append(0)
        student_data.append(sum(student_data[-4: ])/4)        
        my_dictionary[student_id] = student_data
    return my_dictionary
```